# Getting different types of variable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java form in which i have declared different variables of type string , and few variables of type string array and few are collections.
Using getdeclaredfileds of reflection api , i am getting every field of class in my field array variable.
But i want to separate the string variables into one common array. 
array strings into other array and collection fields into other one.

eg:  -    `String abc;
             String def;
   String[] lmn;
String[] opq;
Collection mno;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a utility method:

```
public static Map<Class<?>, List<Field>> getFieldsByType(Field[] fields) {
  Map<Class<?>, List<Field>> result = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<Field>>();
  for (Field field:fields) {
    List<Field> fieldList = result.get(field.getType());
    if (fieldList == null) {
      fieldList = new ArrayList<Field>();
      result.put(field.getType(), fieldList);
    }
    fieldList.add(field);
  }
  return result;
}
```

It separates the fields by type and stores them in a map.

Example usage:

```
Map<Class<?>, List<Field>> map = getFieldsByType(MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields());
List<Field> stringTypeMembers = map.get(String.class);
```

Now `stringTypeMember` contains all class members (fields) that are of type `String`.

Comment: @Andreas_D.....thanks for the help. can u help me in using this function by the sample variables i have given in the question

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just get all the variables and filter them by type using [`Field.getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29)?